# ID LEGO's in sealed bag?

Tags: set-identification

[image]Help please with this sealed bag of LEGO? It has the number 4 on it and I see purple pieces inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That polybag is from [The Ender Dragon (21117)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21117-1), the set with the most of [round plate 1x1 in Dark Purple](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4073&colorID=89&in=A) [BL].

[image]